# What is being computed in this stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue changing the "display" property of an element - .abc1de2 - from "none" to "flex" and vise-versa using js.  I'm attempting to create a dropdown menu, which I've done many times before.  However, the error stems from the style of the .abc1de2 div being computed.

I've searched and searched, but I can't seem to find *what* is being computed.  There's some jinja at the end that I'm pretty sure isn't the cause, because it isn't a parent of the .abc1 div.  I would appreciate some help locating what, exactly, is creating the computed style, and some advice on how to avoid this problem - ie. not being able to overwrite a "read-only" attribute.

Thank you!

Full code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE = HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
     <title>FooterLayoutV1</title>
     <script
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <style>

      /*Override body margins and global fonts*/
      *{
        font-family: arial;
      }
      body{
        margin:0;
      }
      /*Style FOOTER*/
      .a{
        display:flex;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
        width: 100%;
      }
      .ab{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        margin:25px;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
      .abc1{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: space-between;
        justify-content: center;
        width:100%;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
      .abc1 div a{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
      .abc1 * p{
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
      .abc1 * a{
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
      }
      .abc1 * a:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
      }
      .abc2{
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
        .abc3{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
      .abc3d1{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        width:60%;
        margin: 2px;
      }
      .abc3d2{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        margin:2px;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
      }
      .abc3d2 a{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        margin: 4px;
        background-position:center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        border-radius: 2px;
      }
      .abc3d2 a:hover{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
      }
      .abc4{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .abc4 a{
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: rgba(29,29,184,1);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: black;
      }
      .abc4 a:hover{
        color: white;
      }
      .vl{
        height: 12px;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        margin-right: 3px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        background-color: white;
      }
      /*RESPONSIVENESS!*/
      @media screen and (min-width:751px){
        .abc1de1f2{
          display: none;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width:750px){
        .abc1{/*Menu Parent*/
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .abc1d{/*Menu(s)*/
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .abc1 div a{
          align-self: center;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
        .abc3{
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          border:1px solid black;
        }
        .abc3d1, .abc3d2,.abc3d1e1,.abc4{
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          border:1px solid green;
        }
        .abc1de1{
          display:flex;
          width: 100%;
          flex-direction: row !important;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: flex-end;
          border-bottom: : 2px solid white;
        }
        .abc1de2{
          display:none;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .abc1de1f2{
          width:25px;
          height: 25px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
      }
     </style>
    
    </head>

    </body>

    {% block Body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <div class="a" id="base_container">
     <div class="ab" id="sizing_base_container">
      <div class="abc1" id="menu_container_parent">
       <div class="abc1d" id="menu_container_1">
        <div class="abc1de1">
          <p class=abc1de1f1> Menu 1 </p>
          <button class="abc1de1f2" id="menu_button_1"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="abc1de2" id="menu_content_1">
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 1</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 2</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 3</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="abc1d" id="menu_container_2">
        <div class="abc1de1">
          <p class=abc1de1f1> Menu 2 </p>
          <button class="abc1de1f2" id="menu_button_2"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="abc1de2" id="menu_content_2">
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 1</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 2</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 3</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="abc1d" id="menu_container_3">
        <div class="abc1de1">
          <p class=abc1de1f1> Menu 3 </p>
          <button class="abc1de1f2" id="menu_button_3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="abc1de2" id="menu_content_3">
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 1</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 2</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 3</a>
          <a class="abc1de3" href="#">Garbage 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!--{% for item in footer_menu %}
        <div class="abc1d" id="menu_container_{{ loop.index }}">
          <div class="abc1de1">
            <p class=abc1de1f1> {{item[0]}} </p>
            <button class="abc1de1f2" id="menu_button_{{ loop.index }}"</button>
          </div>
          <div class="abc1de2" id="menu_content_{{ loop.index }}">
            {% for n in range(1,item|length) %}
              <a class="abc1de3" href="{{item[n][1]}}">{{item[n][0]}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var i;
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName('abc1de1f2');
        var content = document.getElementsByClassName('abc1de2');

        for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){

          button[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

            this.classList.toggle("active");
            if (content.style.display="none"){
              content.style.display="flex";
            }else{
              content.style.display="none";
            }

          });

        }

        });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: *the error stems from* <--- What error? You didn't post that.

Comment: `if (content.style.display="none")` should be `==` or `===`. By using a single `=`, you're *setting* display to `none`, not comparing it.

Comment: Ha ok that wasn't causing it but good, albeit embarrassing catch.

Comment: The error is as follows:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: "content" is an HTMLCollection, not an element. It doesn't have a "style" property, that's "undefined", so trying to use the "display" property of that throws,